# Populating XYZ coords to a layer when creating point in QField

Tags: coordinates, expression, qfield

I am trying to figure out how to have an expression populate the x,y and possibly Z coords to a point when I create the point in the Field via QField. I know how to extract that information after the point is created. I was curious if there was a way to automatically populate the info in the fields as I create the point. For instance I would like to view the X,Y,Z info through the Attributes as soon as I drop a point for Field data collection.

I am fairly new to QGIS.

Comment: It works well for X and Y coordinates but not for Z. For z I always have a Null value even though I displayed it on the screen... [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlqMM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlqMM.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set default values.

1. Add three float/decimal fields; x/y/z
2. Go to Layer Properties - Attributes Form. Set the default values of the fields to the expression `x($geometry)` / `y($geometry)` / `z($geometry)`:

[image]

The fields will automatically be updated when you add features. (My z does not work because I'm in QGIS, it will work i QField.

[image]

If you dont want the form to show the coordinate fields change "Autogenerate" to "Drag and drop designer" to select the fields you want to show.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-attribute-values) and create [Virtual Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field): fields that are automatically updated when you create / modify features. Use `$x`, `$y` and `$z` as expression for creating the fields and don't forget to set field type to Decimal number (real).

[image]